# Edit the colour of a link on hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hyperlink

This isn't exactly what I'm doing, just a simple way to post the code, but why isn't this working?

```
var links = 'hsla(40, 50%, 50%, 1)';

$('a:hover').css({'color' : links });
```

How should I word the javascript code to make this work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`$('a:hover')` selects all a hovered anchor elements at the time of execution. And it not neccessarily selects all hovered elements on future.

**Using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event**

```js
var links = 'hsla(40, 50%, 50%, 1)';

$('a').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).css({ 'color': links })
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).css({ 'color': 'rgb(85, 26, 139)' })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href>Link 1</a>
<a href>Link 2</a>
<a href>Link 3</a>
```

**Using CSS custom properties (variables)**

```js
var links = 'hsla(40, 50%, 50%, 1)';

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--hover-color', links);
```

```css
a {
  color: rgb(85, 26, 139);
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--hover-color, rgb(85, 26, 139));
}
```

```html
<a href>Link 1</a>
<a href>Link 2</a>
<a href>Link 3</a>
```

Comment: nice, this is working for me, thanks ! 

I have some css which means that the selected link is grey, is there a way to change the mouseleave above, so the color returns to the original colour (normally white, but maybe grey if it is selected.

Comment: not best practice, but just did it with a 'grey! important;' in the css

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly brackets and use a comma instead of a colon:

```
var links = 'hsla(40, 50%, 50%, 1)';

$('a:hover').css('color', links);
```

Comment: But, you should be adding hover styling in a class rather than by code, unless the values are variable?

Comment: yep is from a variable !

Comment: Ok - then you might want to look into using css variables instead of javascript.  Have a look at: [using css variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183839/change-the-background-of-all-elements-in-a-class/64184401#64184401)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when your code executes, it looks for all the `a` elements that are **currently** in a hover state, which is none of them, so nothing happens. Once you actually hover of the `a`, the code that you need to run is already finsihed.

Instead, just do this simply in CSS:

```css
a:hover { color: hsla(40, 50%, 50%, 1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#test">test</a>
```